# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Suspend used to work, now most of the time only if I unplug the HDMI cable and plug it back in

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, suspend

Suspend used to work flawlessly. Then it stopped. I thought the machine was dead, but was able to ssh in. Eventually I realized that if I just unplugged the monitor, and plugged it back in the screen would go live again.

Oddly, sometimes it works anyway. No idea why.
The only other symptom is that my system went from 60 Hz to 29.something. I was just in settings and saw that, so I put it back.

nvidia-smi shows 460.80. I suppose I could update to 460.84.

Is there any way I can diagnose the problem?

Comment: When the screen is black, can you make sure that the monitor has not just simply powered off due to energy saving features?. Many models do unless you configure them differently through the monitor built-in menu.

Comment: I power on the monitor, of course. There is a display saying "no signal". Unplugging and plugging in the cable solves the problem, which of course it would not do if the monitor were powered off. It just worked now, and this makes me think that maybe there is some weirdness when it is 29.9Hz. I will have to try suspending a few times to see